# Compute the kernel and image of a group homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Consider the map: $\varphi:GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_3)\rightarrow\mathbb{Z_3^*}$ with the function being $\varphi(M)=\det(M)$. I've shown that the function is a group homomorphism, and next I have to calculate the kernel and image.

I know the kernel is all the elements which maps to the second identity, written as:

$$\ker(\varphi)=\{M\in GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_3)\mid\det(\varphi)=1\}$$

But how do I do this? I have $3^4=81$ possible 2x2 matricies to check - I've gone through **a lot** of them, but is there an easier way to write this, than writing every single one? Because if this was an exam question, I think I would use a lot of time :(

The same goes for the image.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note that a matrix $M = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ is in the kernel of $\varphi$ if and only if $ad - bc = 1$. So instead of checking every single matrix individually, you can split this into cases and go from there.

Comment: About the image: here $\Bbb Z_3^*$ only has two elements, and you can certainly write up two (say, diagonal) matrices with the given determinants. Also, $GL(2,\Bbb Z_3)$ consists only of *invertible* matrices, not all $81$ matrices.

Comment: On a related note, are you sure you have to calculate the kernel this explicitly? Or would it be enough to note that $\ker \varphi = \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb Z_3) \subset \mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb Z_3)$?